# Signalling the end of an observable, but capturing that signal

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

My specific situation is that I want to run a cache race between localforage and a rest endpoint that looks like:

- start request for resource
- if localforage returns before rest, signal that to subscribers
- when rest returns, signal that to subscribers
- if rest returned before localforage, don't signal the localforage response.

The idea here is that in most cases, localforage will have some, probably out-of-date data that can be returned really quickly, but that the data will be updated when the rest endpoint request completes. I could just do a merge on these two streams, assuming that localforage will always return before the rest request (a not-unreasonable assumption, but still an assumption). The problem is that if the rest response is authoritative and is for some reason faster than the localforage response, the out-of-date cache data will be signaled *after* the correct rest response.

So I kind of want to do a `.race()` on these streams, but not really, since if streamA completes first, I want to merge with streamB. If streamB completes first, I want to cancel streamA.

So far, I've played with `takeUntil` and `race`, and this kind of works:

```
const streamA = Rx.Observable.fromFOO();
const streamB = Rx.Observable.fromBAR().publish();
const cacheRace = streamA.takeUntil(streamB).merge(streamB);
cacheRace.subscribe(listener);
streamB.connect();
```

I need to use the publish / connect thing, because streamB would otherwise actually kick off two REST requests- one for takeUntil and one for merge. This is pretty unsatisfying. It feels like the operator I'm missing is takeUntilButNextOnce() or something, or an operator that merges two streams but completes the merged stream if one of the two streams completes (but doesn't complete if the other completes).

I can *instead* fiddle around with custom observables and/or subjects and just dealing with preserving state inside the closed-over scope, which then lets me use plain old logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `merge` in combination with a `takeUntil` should do it - also just `share` the rest-call, that should take care of the double-request issue that you mentioned.

```
const fromRest$ = myRestService.getDataFromServer().share();
const fromForage$ = ...;
data$ = Observable.merge(
    fromRest$,
    fromForage$.takeUntil(fromRest$)
);
```